# Postfix notation and the equals operator

Tags: notation

Does the equals sign exist in postfix notation?

For example: how would you display 1 + 2 = 3 in postfix notation?

Is it 1 2 + 3?

Answer (score 3):

Equality is a relation, not an operator. However, one can expresss relations as well as operators in postfix notation; in your example one gets the string $$\text{12+3=}\;.$$